# How to run a Videofile using VLC player Using C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, media-player, vlc

```
#include<Windows.h>

#include<direct.h>


    int main()
{
    _chdir`("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
    system("vlc C:\\Users\\Documents\\Wildlife.wmv");

    return 0;
}
```

By using the above code i am successfully able to run the video using vlc player but as the video finishes,still the VLC player window doesn't get close.How to shut the VLC player window?

Please post your valuable suggestion

Comment: What did you try and how did it fail? Did you take a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307395 ?

Comment: I didn't find any solution to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) to pass the correct commandline. See the example below. Note the use of `\"` separators.

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    const char *appname = "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe";
    const char *filename = "c:\\files\\my file.wav";

    STARTUPINFOA si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));

    char buf[MAX_PATH + 300];
    wsprintfA(buf, "%s \"%s\" --play-and-exit", appname, filename);
    CreateProcessA(0, buf, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    return 0;
}
```

Use Unicode if that's a proper Windows program.

Comment: Thanks you @ Barmak

Answer (score 2):

Use option `--play-and-exit` or `vlc://quit`, namely

`system("vlc file:///C:\\Users\\Documents\\Wildlife.wmv --play-and-exit");`

or

`system("vlc file:///C:\\Users\\Documents\\Wildlife.wmv --vlc://quit");`

If you want to use another system call to terminate it, try this on Windows:

`system("taskkill /im vlc.exe");`

Comment: Hello @Daniel, Thanks ! but what i need is i should be able to close the window at any moment of time

Comment: @MukeshPareek uh...why? I don't get it...You can close the window manually...And you can also set a stop time by using option `--stop-time `

Comment: I understand that @ Daniel, But i want to close it through a call only

Comment: @MukeshPareek I edited the answer, which I think can help u.

Comment: @MukeshPareek stop moving the goalposts. You just earned a downvote.

Comment: Thanks once again @Daniel

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Get all process IDs running at that time using `EnumProcesses()`:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629(v=vs.85).aspx
2. Call `OpenProcess()` on each process in that above list and get a `HANDLE`:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx
3. If you managed to get a `HANDLE` call `GetModuleBaseName()` and get the process name:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683196(v=VS.85).aspx
4. Check the name and if you have found your target process in this case "vlc", call `TerminateProcess()`:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=VS.85).aspx

This is just a way...